# Why does Django add characters to images in media folder?

Tags: python, django

I created a new "Game" in my database, and associated it with "batman.jpg". Upon accessing it again, it created a copy of the image called "batman_2KOgdIN.jpg". This is the same with other images. Why is this? Is it okay to keep the copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Django's automatic file duplicate prevention. If you upload a file with the same name as an existing file then Django adds a suffix (e.g. _2KOgdIN) to your filename to make sure it's unique.

To avoid this you can customize file uploading by [writing your own storage system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-file-storage/).